# Velocity Number format issue

Tags: java, server, locale, velocity, number-formatting

We are using velocity as template. We use NumberTool to format number in vm files.

For example

> $!{NUMBER.format('#,##0',$!{amount})} 円

Expected output is for example 9,900円 . It works in almost 99.9999% of the cases. But sometimes for example once in a few months it displays as 9.900円 in our web page.

Does anyone face same problem ? Is there any bug in NumberTool related to Locale or some other issue?

Comment: There's a change in Locale in latest 3.0-SNAPSHOT, see http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/changes.html

Comment: @user7294900 We are using an older version. Its 1.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimals separator can depend on the locale.
To avoid this, you can configure a specific locale to the number tool. For instance, when using a `tools.xml` file:

```
 <tool key="number" class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool" locale="en_US"/>
```

Or you can specify the Locale using Java:

```
numberTool.setLocale("en_US")
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about <tool> attributes to set locale ?

Comment: Yes, even if it could certainly be stated more clearly. See [the tools summary page](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/tools-summary.html#NumberTool). The javadocs shows that NumberTool inherits from LocaleConfig, which has a setLocale() method, but it requires some digging to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

or You can set Locale of you choice as

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

NumberTool nt = new NumberTool();
HashedMap vp = new HashedMap();
vp.put("locale",new Locale("en","IN"));
nt.configure(vp);
context.put("numberTool", nt);
```